# Linear model missing values imputation with dummy variable

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, linear-model, missing-data

I have a timeseries datasets of features published from different sources. The entire dataset spans from 2010 to now. Upon several trials, I realized one of the features $x_1$ have quite a good predictive power in $y$, but the dataset of $x_1$ is not available only after the COVID time. I do not want to simply drop the missing valued, since then they would shrink a 10-year long dataset to a 2-year one, which losses a lot of information. So I decide to impute the missing values with $0$ and add a dummy variable $\mathbb{1}_{x_1}$ that indicates whether or not the feature $x_1$ is missing. So the model I right now have is

$$y = \beta_0^{<1>}+ \beta_2x_2+ \epsilon \;\; \;\;\;\;\;\text{        If Not Covid}$$

$$y = \beta_0^{<2>}+ \beta_1 x_1 +\beta_2 x_2+ \epsilon \;\; \text{        If Covid}$$

The issue with these is twofold. First, $x_1$ and $x_2$ are quite correlated. So in doing so, we are forcing the model to use $x_2$ to explain the dataset, and therefore the weights of $x_1$ will be dismissed, which is not desired.

In addition, Covid variable unavoidably has some effect on $x_2$. That the features behave differently after Covid. Therefore, the missing values is actually MNAR, and simple mean imputation is not desired, nor a regression based one. I am wondering how does other people usually approach this kind of problem

Comment: Without knowing what $x_1$ actually is, it's hard to answer this question.  For example, it could be that it is only relevant/important after COVID, in which case there's no need to add a dummy variable... or it could be that there's another closely-related variable that is available over the full horizon of the dataset, or...

Comment: @jbowman $x_1$ is the mobility dataset published by companies to keet track of how community recovers from covid